# FFMPEG and DXVA2

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I've made a player for IP camera (fullHD H264) with FFMPEG 
I code under windows with Qt.I need the lowest latency as possible and the best result I can get is done whith :

- I got the packet with live555,
- decode with ffmpeg
- display it with SDL.

But with "slow" CPU  I have lot of latency if the bitrate is too high or it can't handle 1080p.

I really want to try hardware acceleration with DXVA2 to see if I can get better performance especially in slowest CPU.

But i really don't know how to proceed. I have to build FFMPEG with --enable-dxva2 and  --enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 ? or Zeranoe build
I have never use Direct X, do I need Direct X knowledge, or ffmpeg with --enable-dxva2 and  --enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 care of everything ?

Thank you

Edit :

Hello, I use this post to help me in my HW acceleration with FFMPEG
[Failed to execute: 0x80070057, when decoding video via ffmpeg with dxva2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602561/failed-to-execute-0x80070057-when-decoding-video-via-ffmpeg-with-dxva2)

I decode the packet with

```
avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &gotPic, &packet);
```

and I'm getting my decoded frame with

```
dxva2_retrieve_data_call(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &gotPic, &packet);
```

I tried to convert it

```
sws_scale(img_convert_affic, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
```

and copy the buffer to a Qimage

```
LastFrame=QImage(w,h,QImage::Format_RGB888);
for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
    memcpy(LastFrame.scanLine(y),pFrameRGB->data[0]+y*pFrameRGB->linesize[0],w*3);
```

I got my picture but with lot of artefact and after few seconds I got a segmentation fault in `dxva2_retrieve_data_call(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &gotPic, &packet);`

Edit :
Problem solved i didn't check if I got a picture before retreiving it.
But the performance are very poor on my desktop cmputer (intel core i5 650, 4GB RAM, ATI HD5800) it consumes 5% more of CPU, 3 times more RAM, and lot of corrupt frame.
It's better on a newer computer, but soft decoder is better.
dxva2_retrieve_data_call and sws_swale consume lot of time when hwaccel is enabled ...

Is there a way to display NV12 picture in Qt (no sws_scale conversion) and there is a way to optimise dxva_retrieve_data_call ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want real GPU acceleration (no copy back), you need to provide DirectX Surface through IDirect3DDeviceManager9(Directx9)/IMFDXGIDeviceManager(Directx11). QT and FFMPEG does not provide it for you. You will also need to provide the DirectX display mechanism.